# ThreeJs strange shadows

Tags: three.js

I have simple scene with one cube and one directional light with shadows enabled.
Cube cast and receive shadow. But shadows on right side of the cube ara strange. In middle of shadowcamera shadow gets darker. Why?

Here is example:

code below:

```
var SCREEN_WIDTH = window.innerWidth - 100;
var SCREEN_HEIGHT = window.innerHeight - 100;

var camera, scene;
var canvasRenderer, webglRenderer;

var container, mesh, geometry, plane;

var windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
var windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;

init();
animate();

function init() {

    container = document.createElement('div');
    document.body.appendChild(container);


    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(30, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 100000);
    camera.position.set(500, 500, -1000);
    camera.lookAt({ x: 0, y: 0, z: 0 });
    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    // LIGHTS
    scene.add(new THREE.AmbientLight(0x666666));

    var light;

    light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xdfebff, 1.75);
    light.position.set(100, 50, 20);
    light.position.multiplyScalar(1.3);

    light.castShadow = true;
    light.shadowCameraVisible = true;

    light.shadowMapWidth = light.shadowMapHeight = 2048;

    var d = 200;

    light.shadowCameraLeft = -d;
    light.shadowCameraRight = d;
    light.shadowCameraTop = d;
    light.shadowCameraBottom = -d;

    light.shadowCameraFar = 500;
    light.shadowDarkness = 0.5;

    //light.shadowBias = 0.001;

    scene.add(light);

    var box = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.CubeGeometry(1000, 500, 100), new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ color: 0xFF0000 }));
    box.castShadow = true;
    box.receiveShadow = true;
    scene.add(box);

    // RENDERER
    webglRenderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    webglRenderer.setSize(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);
    webglRenderer.domElement.style.position = "relative";
    webglRenderer.shadowMapEnabled = true;
    //webglRenderer.shadowMapSoft = true;
    webglRenderer.shadowMapType = THREE.PCFSoftShadowMap;
    //webglRenderer.sortObjects = false;
    //webglRenderer.setFaceCulling(THREE.CullFaceNone);
    //webglRenderer.autoClear = false;
    //webglRenderer.shadowMapCullFace = THREE.CullFaceNone;

    container.appendChild(webglRenderer.domElement);
    window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);
}

function onWindowResize() {
    windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
    windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;

    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

    webglRenderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
}

function animate() {
    var timer = Date.now() * 0.0002;
    //camera.position.x = Math.cos(timer) * 1000;
    //camera.position.z = Math.sin(timer) * 1000;
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    render();
}

function render() {
    camera.lookAt(scene.position);
    webglRenderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

**UPDATE**:
changed fiddler code, now light is outside cube, and light is rotating around cube.
Now my problem is even more visible. When light direction vector is almost perpendicular to cube normal on shadow there is sharp line in the middle of light shadowCamera.

new fiddler code: http://jsfiddle.net/gbwojcg6/2/

Comment: Because i cannot post more then 2 links in post on these images I highlighted what is wrong:
http://imgur.com/r5cpmke
http://imgur.com/KbmivxC

Comment: As I suggested play with the `shadowBias`

Comment: If i set shadowBias to -0.01 there is no self shadowing, if shadowBias = 0.01 there a artifacts on cube corners :(

Comment: By definition a Box can self shadow itself. What you are seeing are the effects of opposite planes on one-another which is not correct and the shadowbias tries to alleviate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seams to be an issue with three.js prior r67, new version fix my problem (darker shadow in the middle of shadowcamera)

Answer (score 2):

The way you have your scene set up currently, the light source is inside the object. 
So there are several things you can do.

1. move the light outside the object
2. reduce the very big value of camera far
3. use a negative shadow bias `light.shadowBias = -0.01;`

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y7ht9gew/)

Comment: What kind of effect does camera.far have on shadows? I figured only light.shadowCameraFar made a difference in this situation.